# Footer background should be angled, but with an uncommon shape in middle

Tags: html, css

I have a page where the footer background is not like the normal. Here an angled background is applied. The main problem is the angled background is not of solid color, there is a shape inside. So I was not able to do it via css. In this image, I am showing that footer:

[image]

I am giving you background image here, so that you can check it for me: 
[Background Shape Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSrGr.png)

Suppose, I want to make html like this:

```
<div class="main-content">Content here</div>
<div class="footer">Footer item here</div>
```

What will be CSS code for this?

I tried like this:

```
.footer {
width:100%;
height: auto;
background: url(image_url) no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position: center center;
}
```

But this does not work. Is there anyone to help me in this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can not make this kind of background indicated in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the backdrop is always at the bottom but sits across both the content and footer, it would be better to put the background in a container that contains both the main content and the footer and then set the position to the bottom:

```
.container {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/OTLuCgc.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

The codes: https://jsfiddle.net/jennift/e3e2Lo6h/2/

Comment: Your answer is fine, but it only works where footer height is fixed. But you know footer height can vary always in respect to elements.

Comment: in that case then yes, your first solution of putting background in the footer will be the way to go. And that would require negative padding to bring the crossover into the main-content area, and then creating a div to hold the (scalable) footer items and then adding padding to the footer to push the footer content down. Here's a revised code: jsfiddle.net/jennift/e3e2Lo6h/6

Comment: Though it was not exact solution in my case, but I got very good idea from your answer. It helped me thinking another way. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pad the top to assure the menu stays on top of the bg (do the math relative to your bg image's size).

You also need to set the position to relative and set the top to negative something to get that top corner to overlap the content element but not that black text (again, do the math relative to your bg image's size).

The use of cover is going to make it tough to do the math but I'll assume you have good reason to use it. Otherwise drop it and stick with a full sized bg.

If you do that the rest of the css looks ok but you may have to position the bg to bottom if you drop cover.

Comment: Can you please give me a solution in fiddle? Actually, I tried in multiple ways, but each time I was failed to reach the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide footer into 3 divs and put same image in those three, then

```
first div -> margin-bottom:-200px;
second div -> margin-bottom:-100px;
```

Comment: I do not understand which divs you indicate? Can you please do something in fiddle for better understanding?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/42mrpsfm/
put image instead of colors
i hope this will be work :)